# Understanding web subsystem and TLS configurations Jboss EAP 6.4

Tags: java, tls1.2, jboss-eap-6

We would like to enforce all the connections both inbound and outbound to use TLSv1.2 protocol.
I would like to understand if the configuration available in web subsystem->connector->ssl  protocol is valid for both inbound and outbound connection

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
                <ssl name="https" key-alias="jbossfuse" password="password" protocol="TLSv1.2" certificate-key-file="C:/Temp/truststore/jbossfuse-dev.jks"/>
            </connector>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
```

Comment: (1) The jbossws connector is used only for inbound HTTPS connections (including requests and responses) on the (indirectly) specified port, typically 8443. Other inbound connections like management and transactions, and all outbound, are not affected. (2) There is no TLSv2 protocol, so this won't work at all.

Comment: It is a typo I meant tlsv1.2

Comment: Is there any official documentation which states it??if you can provide a link it will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure TLSv1.2 enabled protocols for security-realms with the following configuration in  tag.

```
<server-identities>
     <ssl>
          <engine enabled-protocols="TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2" />
          <keystore ... /> 
     </ssl>
   ....
</server-identities>
```